# Changing FIFA 12 firewall status from Moderate to Open on PC?

Tags: pc, fifa-12

I am playing FIFA 12 on PC and the firewall status is always `Moderate` even I have forwarded all necessary ports :

```
9000    9999    UDP     
10000   20000   TCP     
9946    9946    TCP     
9988    9988    TCP     
42124   42124   TCP
```

As I know the best firewall status is `OPEN` so I am wondering how to make the firewall status changed from `Moderate` to `Open` ?

Comment: Just wondering, if you can send and receive packages (ergo: can play FIFA online), why would you want to open further ports? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @atticae, I followed this artice : https://help.ea.com/article/fifa-12-online-ports

Comment: How does that answer my question? Can you play with »moderate« and if yes, why would you want to open more ports?

Comment: With moderate it often lost connection right after opponent found in head to head mode so I want to change to OPEN to see if it will be better.

Comment: @atticae, is your firewall status OPEN ?

Comment: The connection loss when searching for opponents has nothing to do with ports. If a port is open, it is open. There is no in between. If you can play with "moderate" settings, you won't get any improvement if you get the display to show "open". When you find an opponent, FIFA will check if the ping between him and your PC is good enough to ensure a fluent match. If its not (e.g. because you live in different parts of the world), it will abort and you will have to search again.

Comment: You need to forward the ports from your router to your pc AND you need to open the ports in your firewall. Could you have some kind of active firewall (for example the Windows firewall)? Just for testing purposes deactivate / close all your Firewalls with redirected ports from your router and open FIFA. Later harden your system.

Comment: @ayckoster, was you successful in making your firewall status OPEN ? I and my friends did try all of what you suggest but still no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From my research it is impossible or at least very rare for PC players behind a router to reach a FIFA 12 firewall setting better than "moderate".

There is no official statement from EA about what "open" distinguishes from "moderate", but it does **not** seem to have **any negative impact** per se to "*only"* have moderate settings.

If you run into trouble with playing online, entering the EAS FC center or submitting after-match results (e.g. in FUT), you should make sure the FIFA 12 ports are correctly forwarded in your (software or router) firewall, as you did.

If however you have none of these troubles and you are able to play online, you can rest assured that there is nothing to worry about. All other players are playing on "moderate" as well, there is most likely nothing you can do to reach that mystic "open" state and even if so it will not improve your experience. **If ports are open, they are open.** There is no semi-open state that slows down your connection or anything like this.

The connection aborts when searching for Head-to-Head season opponents that you describe are annoying, but normal. They result from the fact that FIFA checks the ping (=how fast the connection is between two PCs in a network) and aborts if you and your opponent are too far apart to have a proper fluent match.

So rest assured, there is nothing wrong with your FIFA or your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the only way to set  to "open" the connection, is only when you will establish a connection without !!! a router .

Also there are many " gaming " routers in the market , but most of them are not compatible for Europe , but only for US .

Forwarding dosnt change a thing , but " fast path " from your Internet provider could improve online gaming experience.

I don't know why , but some thing where not ment to be fixed , the question remains..... why ??

Online gaming is the most fun , in the present days ...!!!!

Fix it !!!!!

Comment: You may be right. I heard that someone got an OPEN status by using wireless.